# SP 2016 - Move files using Content and Structure brought over extra columns

Tags: 2016, move, content-and-structure

Per a user request, I just moved some files from one library to another using Content and Structure. The source library has more columns than the target library. The files brought over the extra columns. Now when the user tries to change the metadata in the columns which belong in the target library, nothing happens.

I used Content and Structure because preserving the version history is important to the user.

1. What can we do to enable metadata changes on the moved files?
2. Is there a way to execute this move that does not cause these problems?

Per request, I am adding additional detail about the steps I took to complete the move.

1. I navigated to the sub-site.
2. Using Site Settings, I went to the Content and Structure area.
3. Within the Site Content and Structure left tree, I selected the source library.
4. Once the files in the source library were displayed in the right pane, I selected the requested files using the check boxes.
5. Using the Actions menu, I selected Move.
6. I selected the destination library in the dialog which opened.
7. The move completed with no errors.

Comment: Please include code used or descriptions of manual steps using UI.

Comment: Is it more easy backup and restore library and, after restore, removing docs that is not interested to? You may do this by Farm scope (by .cmp files) or saving this library as a Template with option do use all content.

Comment: Unfortunately, the move has already been done. That may have been the better option to make the move.